# Remove double quotes from a string- when inputting a value for a function so it can be written just once

Tags: python, pandas, function

So, I have the following code:

`corrresult = df1.drop("COMPRIMISED_ALERT", axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(df1.COMPRIMISED_ALERT))`

I want to turn this into a function, so I can use different variables for both the dataframe and the column I'm dropping/ using for the correlation vector

The code below won't work, as y needs to be entered once with quotes marks and once without.

`def correlation_vector (d,v):  corrresult = d.drop(v, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(d.v)) return corrresult`

Any idea how to fix this without needing to add a third variable as follows (the third would literally be the second without speech marks):

`def correlation_vector (d,v,v2):  corrresult = d.drop(v, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(d.v2)) return corrresult`

If applied to the initial code:
`d = df1  v = "COMPRIMISED_ALERT" v2 = COMPRIMISED_ALERT`

Comment: `df1.COMPRIMISED_ALERT` can be replaced by `df1['COMPRIMISED_ALERT']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the columns in a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) can be retrieved either by *dictionary-like* notation `["col_name"]` or by using the *dot attribute notation* `.col_name` (where the column name is a valid Python variable name), I suggest you to use the former.

```
def correlation_vector(d, v):
    corrresult = d.drop(v, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(d[v])) # <- d[v] instead of d.v 
    return corrresult
```

To call your function, use :

```
correlation_vector(df1, "COMPRIMISED_ALERT")
```